# stageVideo on AIR 2.5

Tags: air

Does anybody know if it is already possible to use StageVideo with Adobe AIR 2.5 on desktop (mac, win, lin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. It is available from FlashPlayer 10.2/AIR 2.6 onwards. Find more [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html) and in [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3330876) on Adobe forums.

Comment: I didn't find any class/method in the {mdm} Zinc 3.0 documentation that looks like it can provide StageVideo. If you have the option of moving to a different tool, why don't you move to AIR 2.6? The pre-release build for it is out.

Comment: Where can I find the pre-release? I searched for it but couldn't find.

Comment: You will have to sign up for the pre-release program here https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=prerelease_interest

Comment: Zinc supports Stage Video API as of version 3.0.23 and has a checkbox for "direct wmode" as of 3.0.24 because it doesn't support fullscreen mode on Mac OS X if the direct wmode is turned on. See http://www.multidmedia.com/support/technotes/?action=detail&id=111

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I could gather, it seems that StageVideo only works in AIR 2.6 FOR TV DEVICES. So, we won't be able to use StageVideo for other profiles until, possibly, AIR 2.7

Answer (score 0):

2.7 doesn't have it either.
If you're looking for video performance a combo of Air 2.6, H.264, Windows and one of the Nvidia cards that support H.264 accelerated Flash (http://www.anandtech.com/show/2876) should work.

On Mac you get it with OSX 10.6.3+ and NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, GeForce 320M or GeForce GT 330M.

I tested on WinXP with a Quadro card and the playback of the 1080p Fast Five trailer was on par with the QuicktimePlayer using only 50% CPU.
On Mac I tested on a MBP with GeForce 320M but the CPU went to around 100% and playback was not smooth.